# TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error loading huge csv data

Tags: python, csv, pandas, opencv

l have a problem loading csv file of (800, 000 , 9) as follow.

```
 npa = pd.read_csv("large_scale_data.csv", usecols=[3,5,6, 7, 8, 9], header=None,low_memory=False)

    for img in char:

        img_cv = cv2.imread(path_img+'/'+ img +'.png')
        images = []
        images_names = []
        WIDTH=[]
        HEIGHT=[]
        for i in range(1, nb_charac):
            if (img==npa.iloc[i,0]):
                coords = npa.iloc[[i]]
                img_charac = img_cv[int(coords[8]):int(coords[9]), int(coords[6]):int(coords[7])]
```

l got an error at this line :

```
 img_charac = img_cv[int(coords[8]):int(coords[9]), int(coords[6]):int(coords[7])]
```

referring to this line

```
npa = pd.read_csv("large_scale_data.csv", usecols=[3,5,6, 7, 8, 9], header=None, low_memory=False)
```

The error is  :

```
        npa = pd.read_csv("large_scale_data.csv", usecols=[3,5,6, 7, 8, 9], header=None,low_memory=False)

        sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (6,7,8,9) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):

            img_charac = img_cv[int(coords[8]):int(coords[9]), int(coords[6]):int(coords[7])]
            TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

However the same code works well with csv file of (10, 000, 9). What's wrong ?

Comment: That means `img_cv` is becoming `None`. Check the documentation for `cv2.imread` to see what it means if it returns a `None`.

Comment: Make sure it's the right path "Warning Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but print img will give you None" per http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html

Comment: Thank you problem solved due to '/' missing in a path. However l get always , sys:1: DtypeWarning: Columns (6,7,8,9) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False. Even if l set low_memory=False . What's wrong ?